# Python error: Index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
seq_sum = []
for i in range(len(sequence)):
    seq_sum[i] = sequence[i] + inv_sequence[i]
print (seq_sum)
```

When I try to run this code it return an error: list assignment index out of range. How can I fix the problem?
sequence and inv_sequence are arrays of integers.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the `range(len(sequence))` here is a bit of an antipattern. Look into the `zip` builtin: `for seq_item, inv_seq_item in zip(sequence, inv_sequence): ...` (see @DeepSpace's solution).

Comment: @deceze Just realized `range()` will take care of that here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`seq_sum[i]` will raise an `IndexError` as the `seq_sum` list is empty. You should use `append` instead:

```
seq_sum = []
for i in range(len(sequence)):
    seq_sum.append(sequence[i] + inv_sequence[i])
print(seq_sum)
```

You can achieve the same result with a prettier code using list comprehension:

```
seq_sum = [seq_elem + inv_elem for seq_elem, inv_elem in zip(sequence, inv_sequence)]
```

You could also use `map` but some would argue its readability:

```
import operator
seq_sum = list(map(operator.add, sequence, inv_sequence))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `seq_sum` to be an empty list. You then try and index in a position other than `0` which results in an `IndexError`.

Expanding a list to make it larger is essentially done with `append`ing, `extend`ing or `slice` assignments. Since you *sequentially* access elements, `seq_num.append` is the best way to go about this.

That is:

```
seq_sum[i] = sequence[i] + inv_sequence[i]
```

Should be instead changed to:

```
seq_sum.append(sequence[i] + inv_sequence[i])
```